# Generic constructor of generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have generic class `ConsumerTest<T, U>` and I plan that `T` is mutable type and `U` is ekvivalent immutable type like `<StringBuilder, String>`, `<MutableInt, Integer>`, `<MutableDouble, Double>`, ... How can I write generic constructor which creates the mutable type from immutable? Here is my attempt:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableDouble;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableInt;

class ConsumerTest<T, U> {

private T value;

public <T, U> ConsumerTest(U u) {
        this.value = new T(u);  // compile error
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsumerTest ctS = new ConsumerTest<StringBuilder, String>("Hello");
        ConsumerTest ctI = new ConsumerTest<MutableInt, Integer>(666);
        ConsumerTest ctD = new ConsumerTest<MutableDouble, Double>(11.11);
}

}
```

Comment: You cant dynamically construct generic Types this way

Comment: Consider passing in a `java.util.Function` that acts as a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another answer states, `new T(u)` is invalid syntax.  One cannot use a type parameter as a new class to instantiate, because there is no guarantee that that particular class's constructor takes exactly one argument of that exact type.

In addition, you've created a generic constructor that defines its *own* `T` and `U`, which shadow the class's declarations of `T` and `U`.  That's why you get a compiler error message such as "Cannot convert T to T".  Remove the declarations of `T` and `U` from the constructor, but not from the class.

You still need to be able to construct an object of type `T` from one of type `U`, so provide a converter function.  Note here that Java's built in `Function`s reverse the sense of `U` and `T` that you have.

```
class ConsumerTest<T, U> {

    private T value;

    public ConsumerTest(U u, Function<U, T> converter) {
        this.value = converter.apply(u);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsumerTest ctS = new ConsumerTest<StringBuilder, String>("Hello", StringBuilder::new);
        ConsumerTest ctI = new ConsumerTest<MutableInt, Integer>(666, MutableInt::new);
        ConsumerTest ctD = new ConsumerTest<MutableDouble, Double>(11.11, MutableDouble::new);
    }
}
```

There may be additional reasons you need to encapsulate this functionality in a class that you haven't shown, but you may not need a class such as `ConsumerTest`.  Just create the functions.

```
Function<String, StringBuilder> ctS = StringBuilder::new;
```

Or you may not need to bother with the functions at all.  Create the mutable objects directly.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for your help. All works now.

Answer (score 2):

`new T(u)` is invalid because `T` isn't a type.  In order to create an instance of a class, you need to know the type, and you don't in that context.